# Can't pass wchar_t to LibXL writeStr

Tags: c++, c, macos, libxl

I'm tring to write Cyrillic characters into a spreadsheet that's being generated in an OSX app:

```
sheet = xlBookAddSheet(book, "Output", 0);
detailFormat = xlBookAddFormat(book, 0);
wchar_t *w_user = (wchar_t*)malloc(max_chars * sizeof(wchar_t));
//get wchar_t characters...
xlSheetWriteStr(sheet, row, column, w_user, detailFormat);
```

but the last line won't compile as the `xlSheetWriteStr` is expecting `const char*` in place of w_user.

According to the [docs](http://libxl.com/spreadsheet.html?lang=c) I should be able to pass in `const wchar_t*`. Is there any way of writing my international characters to a cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibXL provides headers for the `ANSI` and `UNICODE` versions of the functions.

Programs willing to use the unicode version of an API should define the [`UNICODE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407(v=vs.85).aspx) macro. If you are using Visual Studio it is as easy as going to `Project -> Properties -> Character Set` and set it to `Use Unicode Character Set`.

What you see as `xlSheetWriteStr` is actually a macro that ends up having the value `xlSheetWriteStrA` or `xlSheetWriteStrW`. If `UNICODE` is not defined the former, if it is de later.

The function `xlSheetWriteStrA` is declared in `SheetA.h`, whereas `xlSheetWriteStrW` is declared in `SheetW.h`.

**Note:** It is better if you are consistent. If you use the unicode version of a function, use the unicode version of all functions. I say this because in your example I see you are using the ansi version of `xlBookAddSheet`.

**Update:** For the OSX version of the library the macro is **`_UNICODE`**, with the preceding underscore (See libxl.h for details).

Comment: Thanks, it looks like defining `_UNICODE` forces you to use all the Unicode versions of the methods.

Comment: That's accurate. If you don't define it you'll have to choose between using the ANSI version or calling the specific functions directly (`xlSheetWriteStrW` in this case).